# Build error when using OpenGL in my program

Tags: eclipse, opengl, ubuntu

I'm using the following code (which I found on the web) to create a basic OpenGL program:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define window_width  640
#define window_height 480

// Main loop
void main_loop_function()
{
    // Z angle
    static float angle;

    // Clear color (screen)
    // And depth (used internally to block obstructed objects)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse 3.7.2. The program compiles and actually runs, but strangely I get an error showing up in my code. The

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

line has the error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void glClear(unsigned      int) '
>     - Symbol 'GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT' could not be resolved
>     - Symbol 'GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT' could not be resolved

Everything I've tried so far does not remove this error from the IDE. Any help would be welcomed.

NB if I change the line to

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

or

```
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

then the error goes away...

Comment: Can you look in your gl.h and see if GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT and GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT are defined there? You should find something like: /* ClearBufferMask */
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT               0x00000100
#define GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT             0x00000400
#define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT               0x00004000

Comment: @Jarrett yes they're both defined. The program I've written actually compiles and runs absolutely fine, so the compiler is able to find the relevant files and #defines. I think it must be some kind of Eclipse IDE error.

Comment: Yeah, given the fact that it can actually be compiled, I'm guessing it's a problem with your build system and not your source code. Are you using the exact same compiler in the IDE and on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by activating "Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer -> Use active build configuration" and then rebuilding the project. It now finds the symbol.